# compare if an element exists in two lists

Tags: python, list

What would be the easiest and the most elegant way of checking if an element exists in two given lists. For Example, i have two lists as follows ?

```
>>>a, b = ['a', 'b', 'g', 'r'], ['e', 'g', 'l', 1, 'w']
```

Now in the above given lists i want to check if there is any element that exists in both lists. Currently i am doing it as follows

```
def elm_exists(list_a, list_b):
    for elm in list_a:
        if elm in list_b:
            return True
    return False
```

is there a more elegant way of doing this ?

Comment: Are the elements unique within each list? If so you can do this pretty simply using `sets`.

Comment: Yes, the elements within a list are unique.

Comment: @Mike: Wait… why couldn't you do this with sets even if the elements _weren't_ unique? You lose the information that an element exists multiple times, but if all you care is that the element exists, you didn't need that information. (And, if you did, you could always just use a `Counter` instead of a `set` to retain it.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

check elements of `a` and `b` with this:

```
set(a).intersection(b)
```

example:

```
In [44]: nk=set(a).intersection(b)

In [45]: for x in a:
    ...:     if x in nk:
    ...:         print x, 'present in b'
    ...:     else:
    ...:         print x, 'absent in b'
    ...:         
a absent in b
b absent in b
g present in b
r absent in b
```

also:

```
In [47]: timeit(set(a) & set(b))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 940 ns per loop

In [48]: timeit(set(a).intersection(b))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 854 ns per loop

In [49]: timeit([x for x in a if x in b])
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1 us per loop
```

hence use `set(a).intersection(b)`.

Comment: I'm not sure there's much point in timing the results with lists this short. If you just reduce the lengths to 3 and 4 instead of 4 and 5, that's enough to make `list` comparisons faster than either `set` version, at least on my computer, but I don't think that actually means doing an `O(NM)` algorithm is better than and `O(N+M)` one!

Comment: See my edited answer. It depends on the size of your data set, _and_ the frequency of collisions. Which should have been obvious… but it wasn't until I tried to make sense of the numbers. Anyway, in most cases, both of these versions and my generator expression over `set(a)` are more than fast enough, and the OP's original question was about elegance rather than performance, so… I think `intersection` is more elegant and readable than `&`, and the `any…in…for` expression even more so, but YMMV.

Answer (score 9):

This works:

```
>>> l1,l2=['a', 'b', 'g', 'r'], ['e', 'g', 'l', 1, 'w']
>>> list(set(l1)&set(l2))
['g']
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to convert both `list`s to `set`s, just one. I think skipping the unnecessary conversion makes it more readable and elegant.

So, either:

```
set(a).intersection(b)
```

Or:

```
s = set(a)
any(e in s for e in b)
```

The latter has the advantage of short-circuiting as soon as it finds one match, and better expressing the logic, and returning `True` or `False` instead of a non-falsey or falsey `set`, but it is two lines instead of one, if that bothers you. I have no idea whether this advantage cancels out the cost of putting the loop inside a generator expression instead of inside a C function.

Performance results with `list`s this small are almost meaningless, so let's try this:

```
In [373]: a=[random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(10000)]
In [374]: b=[random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(10000)]
In [375]: %timeit(set(a))
10000 loops, best of 3: 180 us per loop
In [376]: s=set(a) # since all versions need to do this
In [391]: %timeit(s & set(b))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 178 us per loop
In [392]: %timeit(s.intersection(b))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 247 us per loop
In [393]: %timeit(discard(e in s for e in b))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 550 ns per loop
In [394]: %timeit(any(e in s for e in b))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 749 ns per loop
In [395]: %timeit(any(e in a for e in b))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.42 us per loop
```

To put the numbers all in the nanosecond scale, add back in the cost of the `set(a)` that all but the last need, and compare the same tests from three Python versions (Apple stock CPython 2.7.2, python.org CPython 3.3.0, Homebrew PyPy 1.9.0/2.7.2, all 64-bit Mac builds):

```
                  CP272  CP330  PyPy
s & set(b)        358000 316000 180500
s.intersection(b) 427000 459000 180900
discard(genexp)   180550 157341  90094
any(genexp)       180749 157334  90208
any(list-genexp)    1420    686    960
```

Now that I think about it, this makes total sense. The odds of getting a collision pretty early on are very high, so the cost of converting the whole thing to a set dominates everything.

Which means we need a new test, with 10000 unique values. Let's repeat the test, with this:

```
In [29]: a, b = list(range(10000)), list(range(10000))
In [30]: random.shuffle(a)
In [31]: random.shuffle(b)

                  CP272  CP330  PyPy
s & set(b)        1277000 1168000 1141000
s.intersection(b) 1165000 1117000 2520000
discard(genexp)   1699000 1271000  770000
any(genexp)        389800  344543  320807
any(list-genexp)    62000   10400    1520
```

These are more reasonable. And they still make sense. If you're comparing the same 10000 elements randomly shuffled, how far into each do you have to go? Not far enough to make the cost of `set`-ifying either of the lists worth doing, much less both of them!

So, let's try a case where there are *no* matches:

```
In [43]: a=list(range(10000, 20000))


                  CP272     CP330     PyPy
s & set(b)           751000    770000  733000
s.intersection(b)    466000    530000 1920000
discard(genexp)     1246000    985000  749000
any(genexp)         1269000    966000  893000
any(list-genexp)  185000000 176000000 5870000
```

I have no idea how PyPy did the last one so fast, but other than that, no surprises here.

So, which one is best?

Clearly, if you expect lots of collisions, you want to avoid making the sets whenever possible—but if you expect few collisions, you want to make at least one set. If you have no idea, I think the safest bet is `any(genexp)`—at worst it's less than 3x as bad as the best, and if there's a chance the collision rate is high, it'll be a lot faster. But you can look at the numbers and see for yourself.

Or, better, of course, time them all against real test data you expect to encounter.

Comment: Nice work (and +1), but the OP asked for the "easiest" and "most elegant", not the fastest!

As a Numpy user, the first function that occurs to me is `np.any(np.in1d(x, y))`. I'd be curious to see how that compares. However, your evidence supports a general rule ... the cost of converting the data usually overwhelms the cost of the test, except when the dataset is very large.

Comment: @cxrodgers: The start of my answer is about "readable" and "elegant", and that's all that was there in the original version, and I think that's still the most important part of the answer. All the other stuff was added later, after the inevitable arguments about what's fastest; the only reason it's so much _longer_ than the important part is that you can keep simplicity simple, but you can't keep performance tests simple.

Answer (score 2):

```
def elm_exists(lista, listb):
    return bool(set(lista) & set(listb))
```

The `bool` function will return `True` for all non-empty containers, and `False` for empty ones. The set intersection (`&`) will return a set of the common elements of the two sets. Note that sets will remove any duplicates.

Alternatively, you can use `set(lista).intersection(listb)` in the `bool` function.

Comment: the `set(listb)` inside the intersection is redundant as `.intersection` takes any iterable(s) as argument

Comment: Also, you don't need `len` here, since `bool(len(x))` is guaranteed to return the same thing as `bool(x)`, both more simply and more efficiently.

Comment: Thanks JonClements and abarnert, changes have been made

Answer (score 0):

This is a other solution,

```
>>> c = [filter(lambda x: x in b, sublist) for sublist in a]
>>> filter (lambda a: a != '', c)
['g']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> y = [1,23,3]
>>> z = [3,432]
>>> (3 in y) and (3 in z)
True
```

Comment: This requires hardcoding every element you want to get checked while his question asks for a way to track all intersections not just one.